В джанго, при работе с удаленным сервером postgres, наблюдаются сильные тормоза. Как победить?
Испробованные варианты:

Локальный сервис postgres на Mac M1 - время выполнения миграции менее 2 мин.
Сервер в локальной сети - время выполнения миграции ~ 2 мин.
Удаленный сервер (в офисе/в облаке), подключение через WireGuard/проброс портов через SSH. Время выполнения той же самой миграции 1,5 часа
На облачном сервере открыл порт 5432 в интернет и подключался напрямую - время не изменилось - 1,5 часа.

На всех серверах debian 12.
При развертывании postgres 15 настройки оставляю по дефолту.

Под миграцией что подразумевается? К сожалению, разные смыслы в этот термин могут вкладываться. Переход с одной версии СУБД на другую. Изменение схемы БД. Изменение данных в БД.

Количество данных одинаково? Сервер находится под большой нагрузкой? Разные накопители: SSD vs HDD? Вмешивается антивирус?

Миграция джанговая - по сути выполняется питоновский код.
Добавляется новая таблица и заполняется данными из старой таблицы - именно эта часть и занимает все время.
Затем из старой таблицы убираем некоторые поля.

Количество данных одинаковое. Перед миграцией делается восстановление базы из бакапа.
Сервер больше ничем не нагружен. Нагрузка на сервер минимальная в процессе (на домашнем сервере наблюдаются редкие всплески на проце).
Везде SSD. Антивирус отсутствует.

Есть подозрение, что тормоза как то связаны с сетью - сам не силен в этом вопросе.
Завтра пойду в офис и проверю в локалке.

Если postgres локальный или в локальной сети - питоновский процесс грузит проц (50-70%), в сети наблюдается поток трафика.
Если postgres на удаленном сервере - питоновский процесс не дает нагрузки (всего 2%), трафик в сети низкий.

В офисной локалке, на тестовом сервере, миграция прошла за 10 мин.
Процессор практически не нагружен, сетевой трафик ~50КБ/сек.

При миграции в Django, необходимо было перенести информацию в новую таблицу.
Запись в новую таблицу проходила по одной за раз:
NewObject(*params).save()
При таком подходе, для добавления каждой записи на postgres улетает отдельный запрос. В условиях пинга ~50 мсек, время работы увеличилось до 1,5 часов.
В итоге миграцию пришлось переписать и добавление всех записей сделать одним запросом к Postgres, используя метод bulk_create в модели Django.
Время сократилось до 30 сек.
